# Transformer rewind Schumacher charger

Tags: transformer, charger

Have been considering rebuilding the transformer in an older 200A Schumacher (auto) battery charger/starter. Some time ago, the transformer itself began making an unsettling buzzing noise, then the burning and smoke started...

It clearly has at least 3 windings in it, the largest of which appears to be the one overheating and burned. Unit was sold by Sears as a H963; a common (repackaged Schumacher SE-6242-A) item with 2/40/200 Amp output.

What advice would you give on rebuilding this on a hobbyist basis - meaning, have done quite a bit of electrical work/soldering/other - and would be interested in this as a learning project. Clearly, it's not a time-or-cost-effective approach.

Have added a few photos. Emboldened by comments here, I've ground off the top of this bad boy; clearly there's a welder in my future(!)

Discoloration/damage to windings will be clear; some questions?

There are 2 gauges of wire on the bobbbin; including coating, these measure out to 0.92mm and 1.22mm diameters. Hoping these are 19G and 17G...

Before I unwind it, is there any way to estimate (weigh?) the quantity of wire I'd need to re-wrap this thing? Would prefer to order all needed before beginning the rebuild.

Having burned the transformer, is it likely the thyristors are also damaged? Plate is based on 8x ST BTW69-200NS thyristors. Without disassembling the entire rectifier plate, I'm not sure I can reliably test these.

There is also a components embedded with the windings - a capacitor?

Is there any downside to painting this thing, now that I've got it apart?

Finally, how practicable is it to re-coat the wire and re-use it? Can anybody point to specific materials/practices/techniques? Is it OK to splice wire together, as long as it remains insulated from other strands?

Interested in your insights.

[image: input side]
[image: output side]

Comment: Unwind the old one, count turns and measure the wire gauge. Rewind accordingly.

Comment: Some photos would be helpful. Typically these transformers are wound on the bobbin separately, then assembled onto the center leg of the  core which is then welded/riveted/bolted etc.closed with the I lamination, and possibly varnished complete. Rewinding an assembled core/bobbin requires a lot of patience, and replacing the insulation if the bobbin is damaged is going to  require some fabrication.

Comment: Hotspots rising in resistance might also lead to a thermal runaway

Comment: Agree with winny. The gauge and turns are the most important. Try to get high temperature rated magnet wire and be careful not to damage the insulation-a shorted turn will result in a repeat performance.

Comment: P.S. Take photos and make sure you wind all new wire in the same direction as the original. Sometimes it makes no difference, but it can when taps are involved.

Comment: any thoughts on my Qs above, gang?